# Writing mocks for arangodb

Tags: javascript, testing, mocking, mocha.js, arangodb

I was wondering if there is something that I can use to mock my database. Say a function `makeRelations` makes relation from a certain node to another. I want to test this function but without actually making a relation in my database. Is there an easy way to do so ? 
I am using `expect` and `mocha` for testing.

Answer (score 0):

To access database (I don't have experience with arangodb), you typically use some driver library. You can fake that driver library calls with [proxyquire](https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire).

Answer (score 0):

You're testing what is likely already tested at some level.